# Obiee dynamic mapping of business models, presentation tables and columns

Tags: analytics, business-intelligence, obiee

I am new to Oracle Business Intelligence software. Although I have experience with with SAP analytics tools.

So we have a working environment (obiee 11g, oracle 11g db) with mapped business models, presentation tables being used in analytics.

But these mappings have to be made manually.

I wonder what would be solution to make dynamic (automatic) generation of business models, presentation tables and columns. Is it possible? DB structure is flexible.

Any thoughts, advises or ideas for solution would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If you drag and drop a table from the physical layer to the BMM layer, a logical table is created and the individual column mappings are automatically generated; However, the physical names are still there and there is no automated way to assign business names. What exactly are you trying to automate?

Comment: Well, we have another custom interface, where users create objects for analysis (indicators), assign them values and so on. This information is written to db and has to be manually mapped in obiee. Can this be somehow automated? Through OBIEE api?

Comment: Are they name-value pairs (e.g. "Sales", 80,000.00) ?  Have you considered a dimensional data model?

Comment: Thanks your help @Victor, but maybe could you be a bit more specific? :) At this moment, data structure can be changed and I want to see if my task is possible to achieve at all (with most simple and suitable data model). Maybe, I try to explain my question more clearly. Is it possible to create 'logical collumn' (at least for now) **without user** controlling OBI Administration tool. Some external way through api or by some **earlier given** conditions in Administration tool.

Comment: OK so you want the logical columns to be automatically defined based on your db?  I dont think that is possible unless you find a way to create the tables with UDML and then using WLST to upload the RPD and bounce.  check http://adventuresinobiee.blogspot.mx/2013/02/scripted-rpd-deployments-using-udml-and.html and https://s3.amazonaws.com/rmc_docs/andreas_nobbmann_udml_xml.pdf